# equivalent to BN_hex2bn

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, biginteger

is there any equivalent to `BN_hex2bn` in C# , I wanna make `BigInteger` from hex string!

am using `BouncyCastel` to create `BigIntegers`

`BigInteger N = new BigInteger("894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", 16);`

now when I compare the value of `BouncyCastel's BigInteger` to `OpenSSL's BN_hex2bn` it gives me different values

```
openssl = 894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C8287

BouncyCastel = 62100066509156017342069496140902949863249758336000796928566441170293728648119
```

I don't understand what is causing it to has a different value , or how can I get the same value as `OpenSSL` !!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7
```

is the hexadecimal representation of the decimal number:

```
62100066509156017342069496140902949863249758336000796928566441170293728648119
```

This means that both numbers are equal. You're just looking at them in differens bases.

Comment: :yeah it also returns a big-endian value!